# LaTex Undefined control Sequence while using MikTex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex, amsmath

I got an Error message from the MikTex console trying to convert my .tex document in pdf. I used the command: pdflatex Test.tex
The Error is Undefined control sequence. It seems LaTex doesn't know the command: \nmid while the command \mid works fine.
this is my whole code:

```
\documentclass [a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin {document}
$\nmid$
\end{document}
```

Edit:
It seems that i'm very dumb 
if you include \usepackage{amssymb} in the code it works.

Comment: what happens if you remove the spaces around `[a4paper]` and at `\begin {document}`?

Answer (score 2):

If you get an error message like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \nmid 

l.5 $\nmid
          $
```

it usually means that you've either misspelled the control sequence, or that is spelled correctly but defined elsewhere (in some package, for example).

In your case, `\nmid` is defined within [`amssymb`](//texdoc.net/pkg/amssymb). You can also identify this symbol within the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive).

Solution: Add `\usepackage{amssymb}` to your preamble.